# How to ensure localState is written to before navigation executes in functional React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a need to cache several values to localStorage in a React project I am working on. To that end, I have created a custom hook, which effectively just exports useState, but attaches a useEffect which watches for changes, and then writes those changes to localStorage. This hook looks as follows:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useLocalStorage<Type>(
  key: string,
  defaultValue: Type
): [Type, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Type>>] {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const storageValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (storageValue === null) {
      return defaultValue;
    } else {
      return JSON.parse(storageValue) as Type;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [key, state]);

  return [state, setState];
}
```

I am then using this hook on a form submission page. Once the user clicks submit, the data needs to be written to localStorage, and then the user needs to be redirected to a new page. This code looks as follows:

```js
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [users, setUsers] = useLocalStorage("users", [] as User[]);

  // submitSignUp is bound to the submit button
  function submitSignUp(
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
  ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setUsers((oldUsers) => [...oldUsers, newUser]);

    // This currently fires before the updated users are written to localstorage, preventing the user from being registered.
    navigate("/profile");
    
  }
```

The problem is, the next page is being loaded before useEffect is fired, resulting in the new data from the form never being added to localStorage. I have tried many variations on this, but have yet to find a way to use custom hooks that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, since I was writing state that was global to the app, I found the most effective way to solve this was to lift the state up above the router, so when the router transition happened, the state was still loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid useEffect in your custom hook and just create your own, extended, setter that will update storage beside updating inner state. Something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useLocalStorage<Type>(
  key: string,
  defaultValue: Type
): [Type, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Type>>] {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const storageValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (storageValue === null) {
      return defaultValue;
    } else {
      return JSON.parse(storageValue) as Type;
    }
  });

  const updateState = (newState: Type) => {
     setState(newState);
     localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newState));
  }

  return [state, updateState]; // AND NOW EXPORT THIS EXTENDED STATE SETTER
}
```

Like this, when calling `updateState` you will be sure that storage update was achieved before proceeding to the next code line, because it does not depend(not waiting) for some other functions to run after it finish its execution.

Comment: The trouble with this is that I pass a function to setState, so this would try to stringify a function, which seems to just write undefined

Comment: You just need to rewrite function to accept function instead of array, if that will make difference. You will rewrite to `const updateState = (stateUpdater: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Type>>) => { setState(stateUpdater); ..... }